# Managing multiple ScheduledFuture instance in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, dictionary, server, scheduled-tasks

Consider the following scenario:
You want to write a Java program that many users can interact with at the same time.
When a user registers a request, the application must create a task for him, which will be done, for example, ten seconds later. But the user can cancel the task any time before it starts.
The question is, what is the best way to implement this scenario?

Consider the following code snippet and optimize it if possible.

```
public class OurServer {
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100);
    Map<User, ScheduledFuture<?>> scheduledFutures = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {}

    public void createTaskRequest (Request req) {
        ScheduledFuture<?> sf = executor.schedule(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //doSomeTasks
                scheduledFutures.remove(req);
            }
        }, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        scheduledFutures.put(req,sf);
    }

    public void cancelTaskRequest (Request req) {
        scheduledFutures.get(req).cancel(true);
    }
}
```

Is this way of using Map and ScheduledFuture classes correct? any better alternatives?

Comment: What shall happen if a user tries to create multiple requests, before his first request has been finished (or even before it has been started)? And you must not use a pure `HashMap` here, it is not thread-safe, but this application is definitely a multithreaded application, otherwise multiple requests could not be registered concurrently.

Comment: @cyberbrain I edited the question and used unique instance of the some Request class instead of User. Thanks for that note. And what should i use instead of using HashMap? Suggest please. Can you write a better alternative?

Comment: If `scheduledFutures` is being used by multiple threads, then use an implementation of [`ConcurrentMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) or, if it makes more sense, add your own synchronization around the reads/writes of the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do several improvements:

1. Extract your `Runnable` into an inner class for better readability (you can use a record with a recent Java version).
2. Use an implementation of `java.util.ConcurrentMap` - Java provides `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap` and `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap`, for your application both should be sufficient.
3. You forgot to remove cancelled requests from your map.
4. You did not try to remove the requests from the executor to prevent even the start.
5. You have to take care that the request for cancellation is not being processed as long as you did not add the result of the call to `executor.schedule` to the map - otherwise the cancellation will be lost. I used the `computeIfAbsent` and `computeIfPresent` to add and remove the entries to the map, those are atomic.
6. Small optimization: I added a custom thread factory that will create "daemon threads". This means that the threads will not prevent your program from exiting. This is just to show you how to do it, in case you need it.

```java
package examples.stackoverflow.q76639234;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class OurServer {
  private final ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100, new OurThreadFactory());
  private final ConcurrentMap<Request, ScheduledFuture<?>> scheduledFutures = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  public void createTaskRequest(Request req) {
    scheduledFutures.computeIfAbsent(req, request -> {
      OurTaskRunnable command = new OurTaskRunnable(request, scheduledFutures);
      return executor.schedule(command, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    });
  }

  public void cancelTaskRequest(Request req) {
    scheduledFutures.computeIfPresent(req, (r, future) -> {
      future.cancel(true);
      return null; // this removes the value from the map
    });

  }

  private record OurTaskRunnable(Request request, Map<Request, ?> schedulerMap) implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
      //doSomeTasks
      schedulerMap.remove(request);
    }
  }

  private static class OurThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    private final ThreadFactory delegate = Executors.defaultThreadFactory();

    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
      Thread thread = delegate.newThread(r);
      thread.setDaemon(true);
      return thread;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can i declare scheduledFutures variable as static for using it in main() method and some anonymous inner classes? is it right way or we have better option?

Comment: You could declare it `static` and use it in `main()` but I would recommend that instead of this, you instanciate a class (e.g. `OurServer`)  in main and have it as member there.Try to minimize your `static` stuff as much as possible to improve testability. (For that you also could use dependency injection from Spring or Google Guice or any other framework for inversion of control)